# Getting dependency error while installing JetBrains TeamCity in Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, teamcity, eclipse-mars

I am trying to install Team City Eclipse Plugin in Eclipse Mars latest release and getting the following error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JetBrains TeamCity Java Code Coverage 6.5.0.18130 (jetbrains.teamcity.feature.codequality.feature.group 6.5.0.18130)
  Missing requirement: JetBrains TeamCity Core (Required) 6.5.0.18130 (jetbrains.teamcity.feature.feature.group 6.5.0.18130) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JetBrains TeamCity Java Code Coverage 6.5.0.18130 (jetbrains.teamcity.feature.codequality.feature.group 6.5.0.18130)
    To: jetbrains.teamcity.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

As it says that required dependency - 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth 0.0.0' could not be found. Is this a bug in Mars release or any plugin/library needs to be added?

I have tried updating the Eclipse - it says already updated. No updates available.

Please throw some pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth` plug-in was removed from Eclipse in release 4.2.

So you need to find a newer release of the code your are trying to install.

Comment: Thanks for this info.